# Why are subqueries in selects slow compared to joins?

Tags: performance, postgresql

I have two queries. The first retrieves some aggregate from another table as a column, using a subquery in the *select* (returns a string concatenation of a column for all rows).

The second query does the same by having a subselect in the *from* and then join the results. This second query however is doing the aggregate on the complete table before joining, but it is much faster (286ms vs 7645ms).

I don't understand why the subquery is so much slower, while the second query does the aggregate on a table with 175k rows (on postgresql 9.5). Using a subselect is much easier to integrate in a query builder, so I would like to use that, and the second query will slow down when the number of records increase. Is there a way to increase the speed of a subselect?

**Query 1:**

```
select kp_No, 
(select string_agg(description,E'\n') from (select nt_Text as description from fgeNote where nt_kp_No=fgeContact.kp_No order by nt_No DESC limit 3) as subquery) as description 
from fgeContact 
where kp_k_No=729;
```

Explain: https://explain.depesz.com/s/8sL

**Query 2:**

```
select kp_No, NoteSummary 
from fgeContact 
LEFT JOIN 
    (select nt_kp_No, string_agg(nt_Text,E'\n') as NoteSummary 
        from 
            (select nt_kp_No, nt_Text from fgeNote ORDER BY nt_No DESC) as sortquery 
        group by nt_kp_No) as joinquery 
    ON joinquery.nt_kp_No=kp_No  
where kp_k_No=729;
```

Explain: https://explain.depesz.com/s/yk9W

Comment: asking this is like "why putting 12 eggs into basket and bringing them all alone is faster then bringing one by one". Because basket is meant for that, because you have only two hands. etc

Answer (score 0):

This is because in the second query you are retrieving all registers in a single scan while in the first one, the subquery is executed one time per each selected register of the master table so, each time, the table should be scanned again.

Even with indexed scans, it is usually more expensive than scanning the whole table, even sequentially (in fact, sequential scan is much faster than indexed scan when when selecting more than a few registers because indexing implies some overhead) and picking only for interesting registers.

But that depends to the actual data distribution too. Its perfecly possible that, for a different value of *kp_k_No*, the second query would become faster if the table contains only one or a few rows with that value for this parameter.

It's a matter of test and guess the different situations that will happen...

Comment: But does that explain the size of the difference? For a specific kp_k_No I get a list back of 92 rows. And, for those rows, in total there are only 96 rows in fgeNote. With a subquery this query takes about 3 seconds. The joined version takes about 20 milliseconds. And that version has to fetch, sort and aggregate the complete fgeNote table (with 175k records in it), and then perform the join. This seems like a lot more work, and 3 seconds to execute the subqueries for those 92 rows seems out of proportion. Thanks for your response b.t.w.